# Goodness-of-fit test for poisson distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, poisson-distribution, goodness-of-fit

*Consider the following sample of times in seconds:*

*5.8, 7.3, 8.9, 7.1, 8.8, 6.4, 7.2, 5.2, 10.1, 8.6, 9.0, 9.3, 6.4, 7, 9.9, 6.8*

*Test the hypothesis that the data is from a Poisson distribution. What is the p-value?*

I am not sure how to go about this since I am only familiar with examples of data with frequencies. but I think I am supposed to use the Chi-square goodness-of-fit test? Is it also ok to use the Kolmogorov-smirnov test?

Comment: The Poisson distribution takes only integer values, and your data is fractional, so you could reject a Poisson hypothesis without any formal testing. Can you give some more details of what your task is?

Comment: I see, how may I get the p-value in this case? And I am learning about hypothesis testing and goodness-of-fit tests (chi-square and k-s, in particular). As given in the example, I just need to test if the sample comes from a Poisson distribution and get the p-value

Comment: I don't think testing this dataset for a Poisson hypothesis makes a lot of pedagogical sense, because it *obviously* isn't Poisson, so I am wondering where you got this task.

Comment: Here is a formal hypothesis test. The test statistic $S$ is the number of observations that are negative or non-integer. The probability of observing $S>0$ under the null hypothesis of a Poisson distribution is zero. The $S$ for your data is greater than zero. Therefore, $p=0$. I actually believe that if you think through this example and carefully compare it to the definition of statistical tests, null hypotheses and p values, you may learn a lot more about the topic than if you apply a standard test in a cookbook fashion.

Comment: This is a great help, thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @StephanKolassa Your first point is excellent, but your suggested test is only for non-negative integers and would not help looking at integer observations which were not Poisson distributed

Comment: @Henry: yes, indeed, it has zero power against many other alternatives, like a negative binomial distribution, or a binomial one. I never claimed otherwise. It's essentially a trivial formalization of the observation that fractional data can't come from a Poisson. (Then again, the proposed trivial test will simultaneously "work" to show that the data can't come from a binomial or negbin distribution, so we can test multiple nulls simultaneously. We don't even need to correct for multiple testing...)

Comment: Where did you find this question? I am with @StephanKolassa that you can conclude, with certainty, that the data did not come from a Poisson.

Comment: Just a guess (and not a defense of the quoted question, which is awful): perhaps the times are intended to be interpreted as waiting times between events and the test should assess whether the events are from a Poisson process.

Comment: @whuber - if so you would be testing these numbers against an exponential distribution.  Just looking at them, they would presumably fail (too concentrated with a range of $5.2$ to $10.1$)

Comment: @Henry Agreed.  But for a novice, it's not a bad dataset to use as an example of this procedure.